# Compiling FreeTDS 0.91 on Ubuntu 11.04 x64

Tags: ubuntu, sql-server, ubuntu-11.04, freetds

I'm working on a Python project that uses DSN-less connections with SQLAlchemy / pyodbc / unixODBC / FreeTDS to fetch data from a SQL Server database. Now I would like to set `client charset` directly in the connection string which is not possible in FreeTDS versions prior to 0.91.

Unfortunately 0.91 is not available in any PPA or as a deb file and as my compiling skills are quite lacking I haven't been able successfully compile it directly from source.

A user over at the Ubuntu Forums seems to [have the same problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1843467).

So, how would I go about compiling `FreeTDS 0.91` on `Ubuntu 11.04 x64`? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I used :

```
    ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --with-unixodbc=/usr
```

to install freetds 0.9.1 to install on ubuntu 11.04.
In /etc/odbcinst.ini

```
    [FreeTDS]
    Description = TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
    Driver = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
    Setup = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsS.so
```

worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

From my notes on Debian Squeeze x64, so might be a bit different on your Ubuntu, I think I just followed the instructions in [the documentation](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/config.htm#EVERYONE). Haven't tested if this specific variant works with e.g. odbc, but it compiles and installs ok.

```
# as root:
# tried gnutls for ssl/tls support.
aptitude install build-essential automake libgnutls-dev
cd /root
#Stable release:
wget ftp://ftp.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/ALPHA/freetds/stable/freetds-stable.tgz
#wget ftp://ftp.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/ALPHA/freetds/current/freetds-current.tgz
tar xvzf freetds-stable.tgz
# of course adjust depending on directory created:
cd freetds-0.91/
# see documentation 
# for what you can configure
# using tdsver 7.2 for fairly recent sql server dbs.
# make sure unixodbc is already installed in advance
# aptitude install unixodbc
# couldn't get openssl or gnutls ssl support working on a fairly clean system
# haven't looked into it further
./configure --disable-server --disable-pool --enable-krb5 --enable-sspi --enable-msdblib --with-tdsver=7.2
make; make install; make clean
# stuff gets installed in /usr/local/lib and other locations
```